# NOT IN em linq utilizando uma sub-consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou usando como base a resposta em:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432954/not-in-clause-in-linq-to-entities

**Preciso fazer uma consulta onde não contiver (NOT IN) os Ids vindos de uma outra consulta.**

A Consulta em SQL é essa:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_boleto.int_IDC, tbl_Admin.* //redução do código
FROM            tbl_boleto INNER JOIN
                         tbl_Admin ON tbl_boleto.int_IDC = tbl_Admin.intid
WHERE        (tbl_boleto.int_IDC NOT IN
                             (SELECT DISTINCT int_IDC
                               FROM            tbl_boleto 
                               WHERE        (sdt_DataReferencia = '20160401'))) AND (tbl_Admin.int_STATUS IN (4, 5))
ORDER BY tbl_Admin.int_STATUS, tbl_Admin.str_URL
```

estou tentando:

```
    var condicaoStatus = new[] { 4, 5 };
    var IdClientesSemBoleto = (from cli in db.Clientes
                             join bol in db.Boletos on cli.ClienteId equals bol.ClienteId
                             where bol.DataReferencia == DataRef && condicaoStatus.Contains(cli.Status)
                             select new {IDC = cli.ClienteId });

        var clientes = db.Boletos
            .Include(i => i.Cliente)
            .Select(s => s.ClienteId)
             .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId));
```

Mas a linha:

```
 .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId));
```

**Da erro:**

> Error CS1061  'int' does not contain a definition for 'ClienteId' and no extension method 'ClienteId' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Como fazer? existe uma forma melhor de ser feita do que essa minha solução?

Comment: Então problema ta no retorno do linq IdClientesSemBoleto ele retorna um objeto não um id apenas vê se consegue ter acesso IdClientesSemBoleto.ClienteId.Contains(s.ClienteId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao fazer `select new {IDC = cli.ClienteId }` o conteúdo de `IdClientesSemBoleto` é uma lista de um tipo anônimo, que apenas contém a propriedade `IDC`. Você não precisa da criação deste tipo, pode-se apenas fazer `select cli.ClienteId`. Isso vai fazer com que `IdClientesSemBoleto` seja uma lista de `int`'s, o que vai facilitar o select abaixo.

Este trecho de código

```
var clientes = db.Boletos
    .Include(i => i.Cliente)
    .Select(s => s.ClienteId)
    .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId));
```

Troque para

```
var clientes = db.Boletos
    .Include(i => i.Cliente)
    .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId))
    .Select(s => s.ClienteId);
```

Comment: funcionou, porém na primeira consulta onde tenho um List de id está trazendo ids repetidos, pois no resultado final trouxe 15 registros e na minha consulta com Distinct trouxe 1, os 15 resultados são identicos

Comment: Bom, ai o problema é com a lógica da tua consulta. Seria o caso de abrir uma nova pergunta, pois o problema é diferente deste aqui.

Comment: na verdade acho que não, pq na minha consulta de exemplo tem o distinct...

tentei...  select   cli.ClienteId ).Distinct(); mas ainda não deu...calma ai..vou testando

Comment: @jbueno não sabia que os tipos anônimos causavam erro também, o que eu pensei que fosse a solução era só a resolução da metade do problema. Obrigado pela informação!

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira Na verdade, eles não dão erro não. Você pode adaptar o select para trabalhar com um tipo também, não teria problema. Mas isso é completamente prolixo, se você só precisa de uma lista de inteiros, faça ele retornar uma lista de inteiros, não uma lista de objetos. É tipo usar uma pistola pra matar uma mosca **_=)_**

Comment: @Dorathoto ainda acho que você deveria abrir uma nova pergunta para solucionar o problema do distinct. Mas se queres uma dica, basicamente você pode fazer um `group by ClienteId` e retornar o primeiro elemento do grupo...

Comment: fiz um             IEnumerable<boleto> filteredList = clientes
  .GroupBy(customer => customer.ClienteId)
  .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(); e ai deu o distinct...vou fazer uma nova pergunta

Answer (score 1):

O problema na ordem em que você está fazendo as coisas. Primeiro, nesta linha:

```
.Select(s => s.ClienteId)
```

Aqui você está transformando toda a sua consulta LINQ em um `IEnumerable<int>`, porque você está selecionando apenas o `ClienteId`

Sendo assim, nesta linha:

```
.Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId));
```

O `s` não contem a propriedade `ClienteId` porque o próprio `s` é o `ClienteId`! Ele é o inteiro que você selecionou na linha anterior.

Então há duas formas de resolver o seu problema:

Trocar a ordem da sua consulta, assim:

```
var clientes = db.Boletos
    .Include(i => i.Cliente)
    .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId));
    .Select(s => s.ClienteId)
```

Ou manter a consulta do jeito que está, fazendo apenas alteração no `Where()`:

```
var clientes = db.Boletos
    .Include(i => i.Cliente)
    .Select(s => s.ClienteId)
    .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s));
```

Comment: Acho que não está certo. Ao fazer um `select new` é criado um tipo anônimo. Isso só vai funcionar se ele retirar o `new` e criar uma lista de inteiros.

Comment: Verdade, não tinha notado que ele estava criando um tipo anônimo. Mas  a própria exception que ele postou mostra que em tempo de execução ele tentou converter para o tipo `int`, então é provável que funcione.

Comment: Desculpe @ThiagoFerreira pela minha ignorância mas não funcionou, tentei e da erro no Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s));
e na primeira forma que vc passou da erro:
'IQueryable<<anonymous type: int ClienteId>>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int>' WMB.Extranet

Comment: @jbueno tentei remover o new do primeiro select mas da erro.

Comment: assim até funcionou mas falta o distinct