# Linq + Lambda, sub-consulta, distinct e not in, como melhorar essa consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Eu tinha a seguinte sintaxe em SQL

```
SELECT  tbl_boleto.int_IDC, tbl_Admin.int_STATUS, tbl_Admin.int_CONVENIO, tbl_Admin.int_PLANO, tbl_Admin.int_RESTRICAO, tbl_Admin.str_URL
FROM            tbl_boleto INNER JOIN
                         tbl_Admin ON tbl_boleto.int_IDC = tbl_Admin.intid
WHERE        (tbl_boleto.int_IDC NOT IN
                             (SELECT DISTINCT int_IDC
                               FROM            tbl_boleto 
                               WHERE        (sdt_DataReferencia = '20160501'))) AND (tbl_Admin.int_STATUS IN (4, 5))
ORDER BY tbl_Admin.int_STATUS, tbl_Admin.str_URL
```

Tentei fazer em linq ou lambda.
[Pergunta original com dúvidas no NOT IN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117067/not-in-em-linq-utilizando-uma-sub-consulta/117104)

No final de tudo consegui fazendo assim
Primeiro criando a lista de inteiros que irá fazer parte do *not in*
Depois fazendo a consulta e o terceiro bloco foi só pra fazer um *distinct*!

Tem como melhorar essa gambiarra?

```
    var IdClientesSemBoleto = (from cli in db.Clientes
                               join bol in db.Boletos on cli.ClienteId equals bol.ClienteId
                               where bol.DataReferencia == DataRef
                               select cli.ClienteId).Distinct();

    var condicaoStatus = new[] { 4, 5 };
    var clientes = db.Boletos
        .Include(i => i.Cliente)
        .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Distinct().Contains(s.ClienteId))
        .Where(i => condicaoStatus.Contains(i.Cliente.Status))
        .OrderBy(o => o.Cliente.Status) //status == byte
        .OrderBy(o => o.Cliente.Url); //url == string

    IEnumerable<boleto> clientesFiltrados= clientes
      .GroupBy(customer => customer.ClienteId)
      .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado da consulta? Trazer todos os clientes (o objeto completo) que tenham boletos?

Comment: a consulta acima esta funcionando, porém 3 etapas pra fazer uma única consulta?
Trazer todos os clientes que NÃO tenham boleto em tal Mes de referencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escrevi essa consulta pelo Tablet, portanto talvez existam erros básicos de sintaxe quais você facilmente vai conseguir adaptar.

Segue um exemplo de consulta utilizando left join:

```
var clientes = (from cliente in db.Clientes
join boleto in db.Boletos on cliente.ClienteId equals boleto.ClienteId 
and boleto.DataReferencia equals DataRef into boletos
from boleto in boletos.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { cliente, boleto })
.Where(c=> c.boleto == null)
.Select(c => c.cliente);
```

Comment: Entendi a lógica vou testar amanhã,